# Using delegate with a static function in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

This is a function that I use it in my app, it works perfectly.

```
class ResenhaEquideosMenuController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

static let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func getLocation() {
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    
    switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                return
            
        case .denied, .restricted:
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Serviços de localização desativados", message: "Por favor, ative os Serviços de Localização nas Configurações do seu dispositivo", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            break
    }
    
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() // função didUpdateLocations controla quando GPS capta atualização do Sensor
}
}
```

But I wanna change this function to a static function just like

```
static func getLocation() { // some code }
```

But I got en error on this part of the code

```
locationManager.delegate = self
```

Cannot assign value of type 'ResenhaEquideosMenuController.Type' to type 'CLLocationManagerDelegate?'

How can I fix that?

Comment: How about instead of using `static` you make a singleton?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: `CLLocationManager` is intentionally implemented with a delegate, in order to encourage a push-based/event-driven/reactive usage pattern (where your code is called in response to changes in location) rather than a pull/polling usage pattern (where your code asks for the location). I wouldn't recommend you circumvent that by shoving it into a singleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to use the delegate with a static function to fix my problem with the CCLocationManager class.

So, based in @DuncanC comment, I create a new class that extends a UIViewController called LocationViewController.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("___ LocationViewController viewDidLoad")
    getLocation()
}

func getLocation() {
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    
    switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                return
            
        case .denied, .restricted:
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Serviçoõs de localização desativados", message: "Por favor, ative os Serviços de Localização nas Configurações do seu dispositivo", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            break
        @unknown default:
            print("erro desconhecido")
    }
    
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() // função didUpdateLocations controla quando GPS capta atualização do Sensor
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let currentLocation = locations.last {
        manager.distanceFilter = 50 // distance changes you want to be informed about (in meters)
        manager.desiredAccuracy = 10 // biggest approximation you tolerate (in meters)
        //manager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation // .automotiveNavigation will stop the updates when the device is not moving
        saveLocationPosition(currentLocation)
    }
}

fileprivate func saveLocationPosition(_ currentLocation: CLLocation) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, forKey: RESconstantes.LATITUDE_USER)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, forKey: RESconstantes.LONGITUDE_USER)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("locationManager error")
    print(error)
}

}
```

When I want to capture the location of the GPS sensor, I just extend a UIViewController using the LocateViewController.

Just like that example below:

```
class ResenhaEquideosMenuController: LocationViewController { ...code }
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Static functions don't depend on any particular instance of the type that they belong to, so referencing `self` from inside one as you're doing:

```
locationManager.delegate = self
```

doesn't make any sense. `self` represents a particular object that provides context for the function call, and that's not available to a static function.

> How can I fix that?

You're going to have to reconsider your reason for wanting to make `getLocation` static, and find a different approach.

Comment: I just wanna reuse the same logic on another UIViewController. Because of that I was trying to create a static function.

Comment: You probably want to either create a base class for both view controllers that implements this function, or create a separate "location manager manager" (that might be a singleton) which provides these services to view controllers that need them.

Comment: A view controller shouldn't have to worry about location... factor the location code out into its own class, and then make an instance of it that you share with any view controller that needs it. You could make it a shared object by providing an accessor to get the shared instance, or you could just give it to each controller that needs it. I wouldn't make it a singleton — usually when people say *singleton* they mean *shared object* — but that's a whole other topic.